# Android 5.0 not supporting samplerExternalOES?

Tags: fragment-shader

I have had a fragment shader working for long time on every phone I tried. After Android 5.0 upgrade is out, neither phone could run the app.

Through debugging, I see that the app crashes at GLES20.glLinkProgram(program)

I see the following error after compiling the shader, which only happens when running Android 5.0

E/Adreno-ES20﹕ : Invalid texture format! Returning error!
E/Adreno-ES20﹕ : Framebuffer color attachment incomplete. Returning GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT!

What I have in my shader is:

```
 #extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require
 // Image texture.
 uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;
 precision mediump float;
```

. . .

Has anybody seen this issue before?

Comment: Did u able to find out reason?

Comment: Unfortunately no :(. I removed the app from google play. I was planning to start investigation again in about 2 weeks. I am just caught up in other things now.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly: There is a crash **inside** `glLinkProgram()`? Was the compilation of the shaders successful, meaning that `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after Android 6.0 update, this problem disappeared.

So, for Android 4.x it works, 5 it doesn't work, and 6.0 it works. I am calling this Android 5.0 issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some docs:

https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_EGL_image_external.txt

> Because of these restrictions, it is possible to
>       bind EGLImages which have internal formats not otherwise supported by
>       OpenGL ES.  For example some implementations may allow EGLImages with
>       planar or interleaved YUV data to be GLES texture target siblings.  It is
>       up to the implementation exactly what formats are accepted.

Sounds like maybe the accepted formats changed? I'd check your format and see if support was dropped for it, or if it's a bug.

Comment: Well, the format does work on anything before 5.0. After 5.0, it stops working. Will this make it a bug?

Comment: Sorry I don't actually know.

Comment: Let's say that the number of bugs in OpenGLES for Android is equal to the number of API since version 16, multiplied by the number of existing GPUs, multiplied by an average of 5 bugs for each GPU.